# How to write a complicated group by query in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have query to write about group by some columns and calculate the result set.

Here is my requirement. I have a table name Table_1 which have 3 columns `id, key, value`. A record is like `id_1 key_1 value_1`. I want to find out which `value` are in the same `id` group and under that `id` group all of `key` has them.

Here is an example:

```
id=id1, key=key1, value=value1
id=id1, key=key1, value=value2
id=id1, key=key2, value=value2
id=id1, key=key2, value=value3
id=id1, key=key3, value=value1
id=id1, key=key3, value=value2
id=id1, key=key3, value=value3

id=id2, key=key1, value=value2
id=id2, key=key1, value=value3
id=id2, key=key2, value=value2
id=id2, key=key2, value=value3
id=id2, key=key3, value=value1
id=id2, key=key3, value=value2
id=id2, key=key3, value=value3
```

the result should `id1, value2` and `id2, value2` `id2, value3`.

You can see all `key` under `id1` have a value `value2`
and all `key` under `id2` have value `value2` and `value3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (ID,KEY,VALUE) form a unique combination i.e. only one instance of VALUE per KEY per ID this should work.

```
with data_k as ( select id 
                      , count(distinct key) no_of_key
               from your_table
                group by id )
     , data_v as ( select id 
                      , value
                      , count(*) no_of_value
               from your_table
                group by id, value )
select distinct data_k.id
       , data_v.value
       , data_k.no_of_key 
       , data_v.no_of_value
from data_k
     join data_v on (data_k.id = data_v.id)
where data_k.no_of_key = data_v.no_of_value
order by data_k.id, data_v.value;
```

I'm not clear what actual results you are expecting, so I've just taken a guess at the projection.

This version works, and [here's a SQL Fiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3f06/19).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think 2 'count over' statements should be count(key) over (partition by id, value) no_of_key, count(value) over (partition by id, key) no_of_value